# How to turn all triggers off in salesforce for a particular user?

Tags: trigger, exception

I have a usecase where for a particular users I want to turn all triggers off. Is there a way to do it from Salesforce lightning UI or java code programatically?

I can't modify the triggers themselves.

Comment: In a word: no. You cannot do this at all, especially for triggers in a managed package. (Also, I assume you meant "apex" rather than "java"?). The triggers have to have specifically coded bypass mechanisms within them.